# What is meant by the set of all possible configuration in a given graph G

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm trying to understand a Solved exercise 2, Chapter 3 - Algorithm design by tardos.

But i'm not getting the idea of the answer.

In short the question is

> We are given two robots located at node a & node b. The robots need to travel to node c and d respectively. The problem is if one of the nodes gets close to each other. "Let's assume the distance is r <= 1 so that if they become close to each other by one node or less" they will have an interference problem, So they won't be able to transmit data to the base station.

The answer is quite long and it does not make any sense to me or I'm not getting its idea.

Anyway I was thinking can't we just perform DFS/BFS to find a path from node a to c, & from b to d. then we modify the DFS/BFS Algorithm so that we keep checking at every movement if the robots are getting close to each other?

Since it's required to solve this problem in polynomial time, I don't think this modification to any of the algorithm "BFS/DFS" will consume a lot of time.

The solution is "From the book"

> This problem can be tricky to think about if we view things at the level of the underlying graph G: for a given configuration of the robots—that is, the current location of each one—it’s not clear what rule we should be using to decide how to move one of the robots next. So instead we apply an idea that can be very useful for situations in which we’re trying to perform this type of search. We observe that our problem looks a lot like a path-finding problem, not in the original graph G but in the space of all possible configurations.
>
> Let us define the following (larger) graph H. The node set of H is the set of all possible configurations of the robots; that is, H consists of all possible pairs of nodes in G. We join two nodes of H by an edge if they represent configurations that could be consecutive in a schedule; that is, (u,v) and (u′,v′)will be joined by an edge in H if one of the pairs u,u′ or v,v′ are equal, and the other pair corresponds to an edge in G.

Why the need for larger graph H?

What does he mean by: The node set of H is the set of all possible configurations of the robots; that is, H consists of all possible pairs of nodes in G.

And what does he mean by: We join two nodes of H by an edge if they represent configurations that could be consecutive in a schedule; that is, (u,v) and (u′,v′) will be joined by an edge in H if one of the pairs u,u′ or v,v′ are equal, and the other pair corresponds to an edge in G.?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the book, but it seems from their answer that at each step they move one robot or the other.  Assuming that, H consists of all possible pairs of nodes that are more than distance r apart.  The nodes in H are adjacent if they can be reached by moving one robot or the other.

There are not enough details in your proposed algorithm to say anything about it.

Comment: Well first of all thanks for your answer. 

I'm confused why the need for another graph H. why we can't solve this problem in the same graph G ?

Comment: "H consists of all possible pairs of nodes that are more than distance r apart." H itself not, but in the proposed solution they later call H' to the graph H with all those possibilities removed so they become unreachable. So yes, your point is right, just clarifying for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway I was thinking can't we just perform DFS/BFS to find a path from node a to c, & from b to d. then we modify the DFS/BFS Algorithm so that we keep checking at every movement if the robots are getting close to each other?

I don't think this would be possible. What you're proposing is to calculate the full path, and *afterwards* check if the given path could work. If not, how would you handle the situation so that when you rerun the algorithm, it won't find *that* pathological path? You could exclude that from the set of possible options, but I don't see think that'd be a good approach.

Suppose a path of length n, and now suppose that the pathology resides in the first step of the given path. Suppose now that this happens every time you recalculate the path. You would have to recalculate the path a lot of times just because the algorithm itself isn't aware of the restrictions needed to get to the right answer.

I think this is the point: the algorithm itself doesn't consider the problem's restrictions, and that is the main problem, because there's no easy way of correcting the given (wrong) solution.

> What does he mean by: The node set of H is the set of all possible configurations of the robots; that is, H consists of all possible pairs of nodes in G.

What they mean by that is that each node in H represents each possible position of the two robots, which is the same as "all possible pairs of nodes in G".

E.g.: graph G has nodes A, B, C, D, E. H will have nodes AB, AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE, CD, CE, DE (consider AB = BA for further analysis).

Let the two robots be named r1 and r2, they start at nodes A and B (given info in the question), so the path will start in node AB in graph H. Next, the possibilities are:

- r1 moves to a neighbor node from A
- r2 moves to a neighbor node from B

(...repeat for each step unitl r1 and r2 each reach its destination).

All these possible positions of the two robots at the same time are the configurations the answer talks about.

> And what does he mean by: We join two nodes of H by an edge if they represent configurations that could be consecutive in a schedule; that is, (u,v) and (u′,v′) will be joined by an edge in H if one of the pairs u,u′ or v,v′ are equal, and the other pair corresponds to an edge in G.?

Let's look at the possibilities from what they state here:

> (u,v) and (u′,v′) will be joined by an edge in H if one of the pairs u,u′ or v,v′ are equal, and the other pair corresponds to an edge in G.

The possibilities are:

- (u,v) and (u,w) / (v,w) is and edge in E. In this case r2 moves to one of the neighbors from its current node.
- (u,v) and (w,v) / (u,w) is and edge in E. In this case r1 moves to one of the neighbors from its current node.

This solution was a bit tricky to me too at first. But after reading it several times and drawing some examples, when I finally bumped into your question, the way you separated each part of the problem then helped me to fully understand each part of the solution. So, a big thanks to you for this question!

Hope it's clearer now for anyone stuck with this problem!